# Android: user can still login without completing account creation

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

My app new user can reg with phone auth only no Email, now app have a 3 activity for reg new user first one to enter phone number second is OTP to enter the sent code and then be sent to 3 activity where user can upload a profile image and name, the problem is with the last acitivty is that if user somehow closed the app without uploading a profile image or setting a name which means that the firebase doesn't reg him at all he would still be able to access the app as normal user.

OTP acitivty:

```
public class OTPActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ActivityOTPBinding binding;
    FirebaseAuth auth;

    String verificationId;
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    private PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallbacks;
    private PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken mResendToken;
    private static final String TAG = "PhoneAuthActivity";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityOTPBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);


        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        dialog.setMessage("Checking...");

        // force prevent canceling the check
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();

        String phoneNumber =  getIntent().getStringExtra("phoneNumber");

        binding.phoneLbl.setText(phoneNumber);

        binding.changePhone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                finish();
            }
        });

        PhoneAuthOptions options = PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(auth)
                .setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
                .setTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .setActivity(OTPActivity.this)
                .setCallbacks(mCallbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
                    @Override
                    public void onVerificationCompleted(@NonNull PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onVerificationFailed(@NonNull FirebaseException e) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(OTPActivity.this, "Verification Failed, Check Phone Number.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.w(TAG, "onVerificationFailed", e);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCodeSent(@NonNull String verifyId, @NonNull PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
                        super.onCodeSent(verifyId, forceResendingToken);
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        verificationId = verifyId;
                        mResendToken = forceResendingToken;

                        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)   getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                        imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
                        binding.otpView.requestFocus();
                        Log.d(TAG, "onCodeSent:" + verifyId);
                    }
                }).build();

        PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options);

        binding.otpView.setOtpCompletionListener(new OnOtpCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onOtpCompleted(String otp) {
                PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationId, otp);
                auth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()){
                            Intent intent = new Intent(OTPActivity.this, SetupProfileActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finishAffinity();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(OTPActivity.this, "Verification Failed, Please Try Again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        binding.resendOTP.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(OTPActivity.this, getString(R.string.code_is_being_resent), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                resendVerificationCode(phoneNumber, mResendToken);
            }
        });
    }

    // [START resend_verification]
    private void resendVerificationCode(String phoneNumber,
                                        PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken token) {
        PhoneAuthOptions options =
                PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(auth)
                        .setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)       // Phone number to verify
                        .setTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // Timeout and unit
                        .setActivity(this)                 // Activity (for callback binding)
                        .setCallbacks(mCallbacks)          // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
                        .setForceResendingToken(token)     // ForceResendingToken from callbacks
                        .build();
        PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options);

    }
    // [END resend_verification]
}
```

Setup Profile:

```
public class SetupProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ActivitySetupProfileBinding binding;
    FirebaseAuth auth;
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    FirebaseStorage storage;
    Uri selectedImage;
    ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivitySetupProfileBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        dialog.setMessage("Uploading Profile Setting...");
        dialog.setCancelable(false);

        binding.profileImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(intent, 45);
            }
        });

        binding.finishBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String name = binding.nameBox.getText().toString();
                if (name.isEmpty()) {
                    binding.nameBox.setError(getString(R.string.cant_be_empty));
                }
                dialog.show();

                if (selectedImage !=null){
                    StorageReference reference = storage.getReference().child("Profiles").child(auth.getUid());
                    reference.putFile(selectedImage).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                reference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                        String imageUrl = uri.toString();

                                        String uid = auth.getUid();
                                        String phone = auth.getCurrentUser().getPhoneNumber();
                                        String name = binding.nameBox.getText().toString().trim();

                                        User user = new User(uid, name, phone, imageUrl);

                                        database.getReference()
                                                .child("Users")
                                                .child(phone)
                                                .setValue(user)
                                                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                                        Intent intent = new Intent(SetupProfileActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                                        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("DisplayUserInfo", MODE_PRIVATE);
                                                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                                                        editor.putString("DisplayName", name);
                                                        editor.putString("DisplayProfileImage", imageUrl);
                                                        editor.apply();
                                                        startActivity(intent);
                                                        finish();
                                                    }
                                                });
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    String uid = auth.getUid();
                    String phone = auth.getCurrentUser().getPhoneNumber();
                    User user = new User(uid, name, phone, "No Image");
                    database.getReference()
                            .child("Users")
                            .child(phone)
                            .setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                                Intent intent = new Intent(SetupProfileActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                finish();
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(SetupProfileActivity.this, "Failed To Reg Account", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (data !=null){
            if (data.getData() !=null){
                binding.profileImageView.setImageURI(data.getData());
                selectedImage = data.getData();
            }
        }
    }

    // check if want to exit
    boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
            super.onBackPressed();
            return;
        }

        this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
        Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.click_again_to_Exit), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                doubleBackToExitPressedOnce=false;
            }
        }, 2000);
    }
}
```

Code used to autologin :

```
//AutoLogin
if (auth.getCurrentUser() !=null){
    Intent intent = new Intent(PhoneLoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: post the code where you directly open main activity if the user is logged in

Comment: //AutoLogin
        if (auth.getCurrentUser() !=null){
            Intent intent = new Intent(PhoneLoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple way to handle your situation is to keep a boolean variable like "isProfileComplete" on User Profile. Set this to true once you receive all required info from the user on Setup Profile. Check this value on your Launcher Activity, if its false then redirect user to Setup Profile page else on your Landing page.

**Edit**

You need minor changes in your auto login code section

```
if (auth.getCurrentUser() !=null){
    Intent intent; 
    if(isProfileComplete())
      intent = new Intent(PhoneLoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    else
      intent = new Intent(PhoneLoginActivity.this, SetupProfileActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}

private boolean isProfileComplete(){
  //get User object for the logged in user using SharedPreferences or FirebaseDB
  return user.isProfileComplete
}
```

Comment: didn't work it result in splash activity to keep loop

Comment: any other solution

Comment: How is Splash Looping?? You need to edit your AutoLogin code here. Will edit my answer  to make you clear.

Comment: now there is a problem if user closes while not completing the reg he would be forced to be inside Reg activity or setup he can't go to Login activity even login button wouldn't work